# typeahead-input-formatter not working when pasting the value in input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have used angular UI Bootstrap typeahead Directive. I have id as a model value but I want to display "id + name" as a selected option once user select the option. For that I am executing formatLabel function like this :

```
typeahead-input-formatter='formatLabel($model)'
```

In controller,

```
$scope.formatLabel = function (model) {
          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.abc.length; i++) {
            if (model === $scope.abc[i].id) {
              return $scope.abc[i].id + ' ' + $scope.abc[i].name;
            }
          }
        };
```

where $scope.abc is the input model.
All above works perfect when type using keyboard in input, But when I paste the value in input then select the option it is only displaying the model value (id only)as a selected option.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A plunker would have helped with an answer. Anyways as per Angular UI doc the `typeahead-input-formatter` is only triggered on select